# Function given as an integral

Tags: calculus

> Given
> $$
> H(x) = \frac{1}{x}
>        \int_2^x \left[2\sqrt{4+t^{3}}-H'(t)\right]dt
> $$
> I gotta find the value of $H'(2)$.

I rewrote it as
$$x\cdot H(x)=\int_2^x \left[2\sqrt{4+t^3}-H'(t)\right]dt$$
and derivating it, I found
$$H(x)+x\cdot H'(x)=2\sqrt{4+x^{3}}-H'(x)-2\sqrt{12}+H'(2)$$
which gave me, for $x=2$
$$H'(2)=-\frac{H(2)}{2}$$
But, using the first expression for $H$, is $H(2)=0$ because of the integral? If so, then $H'(2)=0$?

Comment: The derivative of the RHS of the first equation you wrote is just $2 \sqrt{4 + x^3} - H'(x)$. There's no extra constant when you differentiate it.

Comment: So I don't substitute for  $t=x$ and $t=2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $H(2)=0$ is in built.
Let us rewrite the eq. as
$$xH=\int_{2}^{x} 2\sqrt{2+t^2} dt-\int_{2}^{x} H'(t) dt$$
Differentiationg this eqn, using Lebnitz, we get
$$H(x)+xH'(x)=2\sqrt{4+x^2}-H'(x)$$
By putting $x=2$, we get
$$H(2)+2H'(2)=4 \sqrt{2}-H'(2) \implies 3H'(2)= 4\sqrt{2} \implies H'(2)=\frac{4 \sqrt{2}}{3}.$$